# change sj:radio value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

How to change the radio button value in jquery?
this is the radio button tag,

and i want to change the value in the javascript file

```
<sj:radio id="lang" name="lang" list="#{1:'Arabic', 2:'English'}" value="1" />
```

Comment: This should work $('#lang').val("2");

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying change the val you can do it like this:

```
$('sj\\:radio').val("your_value").
```

If you are trying to change the value attribute that you can see in dev tools, you can go with:

```
$('sj\\:radio').attr('value','2')
```

I used the selector $('sj\:radio'), in case you used like this and didn't worked : $('sj:radio').